# Creating custom URL for async content

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, javascript, urls

I am using a fully asynchronous Javascript/jQuery portfolio gallery (Grid Gallery template in Photolux theme).

When a portfolio item is clicked, the item's details loads. It is built-in in the template that if there is a `#` followed by an `ID` in the URL (ie.: `domain.com/#23`) then that portfolio's details opens.

I would like to rewrite this to have a human-readable URL, such as `domain.com/my-favorite-images/`

How is this achieveable in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

In general the pretty permalinks are domain of [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) in WordPress. But they convert the links into query variables for *back–end PHP* side of it.

Hashbang links are domain of JavaScript. It is impossible to say how easy would be to change them, without very specific knowledge of how theme's JS implements them.